# Basic c question - What exactly happens when you declare a static variable in c?

Tags: c, static, static-variables

I'm trying to learn how static variable work in c for when they are defined in a given function. For example, when I write the following:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
void inc() {
  static int c = 0;
  c++;
  printf("%d\n", c);
}

int main(void) {
  inc();
  inc();
  inc();
  return 0;
}
```

The expected output is obviously:

```
1
2
3
```

On the first call of the function, the static variable c is defined and given the value of 0, which makes perfect sense. It is the incremented and printed. However, on the second call to `inc()` why is it that the integer c is maintained and not set to zero, even though the code literally says `static int c = 0;`. What mechanism in the compiler stops c from having it's value set to zero like during the first call?

Comment: Its more about scopes than variable being static.

Comment: Did you compare the behaviour to `static int c; c=0;` ? You might want to do that and mention it in the question to make things clearer. E.g. as in "Why is the behaviour not identical?"

Comment: Is your question "what exactly happens?" or "why do compilers act like that?" . The latter is answered by Sourav below. The former cannot really be answered, since compilers (and linkers) are quite free how to implement the required externally observable behaviour.

Comment: `c` isn't set to 0 on the first call.  It's already 0 when the file containing the function is loaded.  `c` is in static memory, which basically means it's like a global variable except its name is only available inside `inc`.

Comment: Very similar questions, but I hesitate to mark as duplicate. Probably an interesting read nonetheless : [Where are static variables stored in C and C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/93039/where-are-static-variables-stored-in-c-and-c), [how do static variables inside functions work?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7740761/how-do-static-variables-inside-functions-work)

Comment: the way compilers implement static variables is usually the same as global variables, only that they use linker tricks to hide them -- like [decorating their names](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/471885/308316), not quite dissimilar to how c++ compilers are implementing functions with the same name but different signatures.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Quoting `C11`, chapter §6.2.4, Storage durations of objects (*emphasis mine*)

> An object whose identifier is declared without the storage-class specifier
>   `_Thread_local`, and either with external or internal linkage or with the storage-class
>   specifier `static`, has *static storage duration*. **Its lifetime is the entire execution of the
>   program and its stored value is initialized only once, prior to program startup.**

So, the initialization inside the function call does not take place on every call to the function. It only happens once, before the execution of `main()` starts. The variable retains the last stored value through the program execution, i.e, the value is retained between the  repeated calls to the function.

Comment: For those folk (like me) who like to collect differences between C and C++, note that in the latter, the `static` is initialised the first time it's encountered in program flow as specified by the source code: you can also initialise to the result of a function call.

Comment: @Bathsheba yes, and the constructors of function-local static variables will also be called when the function is first run, not before main as the other static constructors.

Answer (score -1):

Its lifetime is the entire execution of the program and its valie is intialized before program starts and only once.

Comment: Please explain how this provides additional insight to the older and upvoted answer.